# MS Word won't read ODF file written with QTextDocumentWriter

Tags: qt, odf, opendocument

I gave a try for QTextDocumentWriter and managed to generate ODF file copy-pasting [sample code](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq27-odfwriter.html#writingthebill). The code looked pretty straightforward. But although OpenOffice opens generated document very well, my MS Word 2010 reports an error. If I choose to ignore the error, Word does open the document but it looks not the same as in OpenOffice (looks like a part of formatting lost).

Has anyone faced the same. Is there any configuration of the writer I missed that can help fixing this?

Comment: hm, I tried to open and save generated document via lpod-python library an got and error message:
KeyError: "There is no item named 'meta.xml' in the archive"
Seems the files generated by QTextDocumentWriter are 'slightly' incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

MS Word doesn't open .odt that are version >1.1 
Microsoft quality and support of standards are as good as always.